# How to get all the element value which have the same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a requirement where I need to get all the values of the elements called ID, concatenate them and display. I've the solution with me now. Wouldn't there be a better way to get the values?

Input:

```
<Response>
    <Error/>
    <Data>
        <Account>
            <IDs>
                <ID>386</ID>
                <ID>287</ID>
                <ID>997</ID>
                <ID>2709</ID>
            </IDs>
        </Account>
    </Data>
</Response>
```

Hard coded XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
            <xsl:copy-of select="concat(//Account/IDs/ID[1]/text(),'$',//Account/IDs/ID[2]/text(),'$',//Account/IDs/ID[3]/text(),'$',//Account/IDs/ID[4]/text() )"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
386$287$997$2709
```

Dynamic XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/> 
    <xsl:template match="ID">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(., '$')"/>
    </xsl:template>        
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which gives the same output as above:

```
386$287$997$2709$
```

So both works for me. But what I was thinking that, is there a way where I can set the XPATH dynamically in the **Hard coded XSL**, so that it picks up all the value of ID, instead of mentioning 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0? You would be able to do it in a single xpath expression then without hard-coding the indexes.

Comment: I can give it a try.

Comment: You could use the string-join function if you could use XSLT 2.0... `string-join(//Account/IDs/ID, '$')`

Comment: Thumps up @Tim C

Comment: How about adding one more criteria in the same XPATH, where it also prints 'EMPTY' in case there is no ID

Comment: So basically the output becomes `EMPTY`

Comment: You could do something like `(string-join(//Account/IDs/ID, '$'), 'EMPTY')[normalize-space()][1]` for example. But if you can't get it to work, feel free to ask a whole new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2 and 3 you can do it directly with pure XPath, as Tim has already pointed out using the function `string-join`, `string-join(//Account/IDs/ID, '$')`, but you can as well rely on `xsl:value-of` and `<xsl:value-of select="//Account/IDs/ID" separator="$"/>`.